# Consulta SELECT con dos claves foraneas que refieren a una misma tabla en Postgre

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo dos tablas en PostgreSQL de la siguiente manera:

Tabla "users", con los siguientes campos:

- user_id : integer incremental, y clave primaria de la tabla
- user_name : varchar

y otra tabla "data" con los siguientes campos:

- data_id: integer incremental, y clave primaria
- descripcion: varchar
- created_by: integer y clave foranea de user_id de la tabla users
- modified_by: integer y clave foranea de user_id de la tabla users

La consulta que quiero obtener, es la data_id, descripcion, y el user_name de los usuarios referenciados en created_by y modified_by

Lo que probe fue lo siguiente:

```
SELECT data_id, descripcion, users.user_name FROM data 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = data.created_by
LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = data.modified_by
```

y me dio el error que ya esperaba:

> table name "users" specified more than once

Además de que en el `select` estoy llamando a `user_name` una sola vez, y no dos como debiera ser, pero no tengo idea de que mas hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba del modo siguiente:

- Dale un alías a la tabla `users` por cada vez que la invocas en el `LEFT JOIN`
- En el `SELECT` vas a elegir mas de una vez de la misma tabla los valores deseados, pero en vez de hacerlo a la tabla `users` lo harías a alguno de los 2 alias que le colocaste a dicha tabla

Código

```
SELECT data_id, 
       descripcion, 
       users1.user_name AS userCreatedBy,
       users2.user_name AS userModifieddBy
FROM data 
LEFT JOIN users AS users1 ON users1.user_id = data.created_by
LEFT JOIN users AS users2 ON users2.user_id = data.modified_by
```

Answer (score 0):

tienes que usar alias.

```
SELECT data_id, descripcion, users.user_name, users_two.user_name FROM data 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = data.created_by
LEFT JOIN users as users_two ON users_two.user_id = data.modified_by
```

Comment: Esta respuesta sirve como solucionar la pregunta, pero ha sido reportada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Sería ideal que la completaras indicando qué es un alias o cómo lo pusiste en el código. Las respuestas que son básicamente código no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Lee [answer] para más información.